# Run script or command after boot

Tags: raspbian, boot, raspbian-jessie, script

I need to run `sudo mount -a` after boot since auto mount of the share doesn't happen as needed (`/etc/fstab` contains the right code for that ).

How can I do this on Jessie Pixel?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Write a `systemd` or `init` service that does what you want.

you can also use `cron` by running:

```
sudo crontab -e
```

Then:

```
@reboot /my/special/script.sh
```

Don't forget to `chmod` the script (`chmod 744`). This should run your script once after reboot.

Comment: I tried 'sudo crontab -e' and 'crontab -e' , 
adding : @reboot mount -a
both - no success.
even tried : sudo mount -a
again - so success

Comment: Any idea why isn't working??

Comment: what's not working ? is the script executed ? add some logging or write to some file.

Comment: I did not write script but the command "mount -a" to mount shares. After boot I write in terminal the command and shares are mounted immediately

Comment: try something like `touch /some/file` let's see if that command is actually gets called; you can also check the logs or just redirect whatever `mount` will return to some file and see what's wrong.

Comment: 1. The touch part went ok. 2. I tried mount -a >>log - which was created empty ( meaning that is it executed )... but still- not mounted.

Comment: okay then your question is answered. try to redirect stderr using `mount -a 2> log.err`

Comment: I did as offered @reboot mount -a 2 > log.log. Still file is empty

Comment: can't tell open a new question for the mount issue

Comment: Already did. No answer. What is the purpose of 2 in syntax?

Comment: 2> redirects stderr messages (error messages) to some other file. [read this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/an-introduction-to-linux-i-o-redirection) for more details.

Comment: after rewriting 2> with no whitespaces - the log file noted that:
"mount error(101): Network is unreachable"

Comment: there you have it then, maybe write a script that waits for whatever interface you use to get an ip and mount, you can also write some script in `/etc/network/if-up.d` that does the mounting as soon as the interface is up and has an ip.

Comment: The answer was found in a comment in other question. It is actually regarding the fact that the network is not sequenced for mount in that particular time. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Answered in another thread. 
I is all about timing

> `https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/33607/68038`